# Access LAN computers via VPN connection

Tags: openvpn, vpn, lan

I am wanting to put a VPN server on one of machines on my LAN and expose this VPN service to the internet.

Once a client (laptop) is connected to my VPN service from outside my LAN I want to be able to access other services/devices on my LAN such as (s)ftp, ssh, http(s) which are on different machines on the LAN.

Is there any special configurations I need to make to openvpn on the host or client to allow this setup, or am I forced to get every machine I want to connect to to open a VPN connection to the VPN host in order for my client device to be able to communicate with them.

Edit:: If it was not clear I am trying to access the vpn hosts local LAN services. NOT the laptops:

```
laptop (client) --> server (vpn host) --> ssh (located on vpn hosts lan)
                                          ^ trying to connect here
```

From my knowledge all the suggestions so far are for connecting to services on the laptops (clients) local LAN RATHER than the hosts LAN.

The software being used is openvpn.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, it might be an IP routing issue: either the service hosts on the LAN or the router serving them must somehow get to know that the IP address the laptop receives when VPN connection is established is reachable by going through the VPN host. If the client's VPN IP address belongs to the LAN's IP segment, then the VPN host must do Proxy ARP for the client's IP address; if the VPN IP address is assigned from a different segment, then the LAN router must have a route that directs access to the VPN IPs through the VPN host.

Comment: you can have better and painless setup by setting up an OpenVPN server on cheap external 5$ per month VPS service. and host a VPN client inside your network on a virtual machine. `

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [How to set up OpenVPN to let the VPN clients to access all the servers inside the server LAN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/418354/how-to-set-up-openvpn-to-let-the-vpn-clients-to-access-all-the-servers-inside-th)

You need to push a route to the clients when they connect, and enable IP Forwarding with the proper iptables rules.